# Flutter and OneSignal, how to catch notification in different page than where it's initialized

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I'm running init on the front page of my app:

```
    OneSignal.shared.init("app-id");
```

And catching notifications and then doing something if app is in view:

```
    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) { 
        // doing stuff here, works great on front page
    }
```

That works fine in frontpage. But, I'd like to catch the notifications and do specific tasks on other pages as well, that however does not work.

Tried to use: setNotificationReceivedHandler in other pages, but no luck, it always uses the front page's setNotificationReceivedHandler instead.

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it to work.

The whole init process has to be done in every view where you want to catch notification, the latest loaded init is the one which is being processed.